# How can I get rid of a gap between 2 divs

Tags: html-email

I have two images, I would like them to line up flush with no gap.  On most devices it is fine, on Outlook 2007 there is a small gap.

Both images are within a `<div>` which I am using for my layout.  The div has no margin or padding, none of the tables have margin or padding.  I have set `border-collapse: collapse;` on my table too.

I have never quite managed to solve this problem.  Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.

Here is a JS fiddle.  It doesn't contain all of my code but I think it has the relevant stuff.  https://jsfiddle.net/tfn2tk8b/

[image]

Comment: Can you post the full html/css as a jfiddle example so we know exactly what you've got? I know a lot of times placing a blank comment `<!-- --> in the code between the div's can fix this issue.

Comment: You missed a ` from your code.  Cheers I will try that.

Comment: Well in your jsfiddle, there's no space in between the images so it might be something with the code for the email host you are using.

Comment: I'm using MailChimp, and I'm testing on a variety of email browsers.